# What is the best way to enable different rules for different subnets in Snort?

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

We have snort running on one of our servers which has a network interface that has a subnet configuration of `192.168.0.0/16` I want to enable a specific rule, for example a chat rule with the sid:2002027, to `192.168.1.0/24` but I don't want the rule be active for `192.168.2.0/24`. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
alert tcp any 6666:7000 -> any any (msg:"ET CHAT IRC PING command"; flow:from_server,established; content:"PING|20|"; depth:5; flowbits:set,is_proto_irc; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2002027; classtype:misc-activity; sid:2002027; rev:13;)
```

And also, the any keyword like the one in the above rule should be limited to `192.168.1.0/24`. Otherwise it would affect `192.168.2.0/24`. And I am trying to automate this because we can have many subnets and many different rules for these subnets.

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple configurations feature of snort.

> Snort now supports multiple configurations based on VLAN Id or IP subnet within a single instance of Snort. This will
>   allow administrators to specify multiple snort configuration files and bind each configuration to one or more VLANs
>   or subnets rather than running one Snort for each configuration required. Each unique snort configuration file will
>   create a new configuration instance within snort.

For details refer "Multiple configurations" in https://www.snort.org/documents/snort-users-manual

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this specific rule to match anything in the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 then just define that in the rule header. If 192.168.1.0/24 is the range for your server IPs then the header of the rule would just look something like below:

alert tcp 192.168.1.0/24 6666:7000 -> any any

If you want to use this in multiple rules and be able to add IP addresses then you should define a [variable](https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-variables) for these IP addresses and use the variable in all of your rules. For example in your snort.conf you can add something like the following:

ipvar MY_SERVERS [192.168.1.0/24]

And in all of your rules you would define the header like the following:

alert tcp $MY_SERVERS 6666:7000 -> any any

You can even encompass the entire /16 and just omit the /24 for this variable as well by doing defining the variable as follows:

ipvar MY_SERVERS [192.168.0.0/16, !192.168.2.0/24]

This would make the variable include all IP addresses with in 192.168.0.0/16 subnet with the exception of IPs that fall within the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet range.